# Build DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

I downloaded DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra (DDAC) from this [page](https://downloads.datastax.com/#ddac).
**nodetool.bat** runs `cassandra.in.bat`, `cassandra.in.bat` in one of the statements requires `"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\build` folder. However, this build folder does not exist in the downloaded DDAC archive:

[image]

---

I also tried building with [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) tool, but Ant requires `build.xml`, which also doesn't exist.

**How to build DDAC?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no source code for DDAC available, so you can't build it. DDAC is binary compatible with Cassandra, but includes fixes that aren't available in the OSS version.

Also, Windows doesn't belong to [supported platforms](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/supportedPlatforms.html), even for development. If you want to run DDAC on Windows, either use [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/datastax/ddac), or virtual machine with Linux inside.